# Minimap not appearing in MW3 Single Player XBox 360 Hardened Level

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I am just starting MW3 on my XBox 360 and I am not getting a minimap, which I think is supposed to show up in the upper left-hand corner of the screen. Is this an option that I have to turn on somehow? I'm only playing on "hardened."

Comment: I don't *think* there's usually a minimap on the single player levels.  It's been a little while though.  I'm nearly 100% certain there's no option for it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I double checked several missions, confirmed that there is no minimap in campaign.